# Winforms Webbrowser control URL Validation

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to validate a winform web browser control url when a button is clicked. I would like to see if the web browser's current url matches a certain url. When I try to run this code the program freezes

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Check to see if web browser is at URL
    if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString != "www.google.com" || webBrowser1.Url.ToString == null)
 { 
    // Goto webpage
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("www.google.ca");
 }
 else {
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("first").InnerText = "blah";
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("second").InnerText = "blah";
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this the Windows Forms web browser control, or the WPF web browser control? There's no such thing as a "C# WebBrowser control"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Win forms

Comment: I added the [tag:winforms] tag to your question so the Windows Forms experts will be more likely to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://www.google.ca");

            // Check to see if web browser is at URL
            if (webBrowser1.Url != null)
            {
                if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() != "https://www.google.com" || webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == null)
                {
                    // Goto webpage
                    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("www.google.ca");
                }
                else
                {
                    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("first").InnerText = "blah";
                    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("second").InnerText = "blah";
                }
            }

        }
```

1) Please use the schema with the URL.

2) Use ToString() as a function.

Comment: No, I need it from the web browser control

Comment: Hi SkipDis, Kindly check the above code and let me know if you need more input.

Comment: Hi, I get the NullReference Error

Comment: Can you tell me at which line?